# error opening device in gammu through php

Tags: php, linux, gammu

i am trying to send sms through gammu in php. when i run the code in console it works perfectly, when i execute it through exec function it shows error opening device it does not exist. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I guess when testing it in the command line you use your own user, while PHP is being executed by a webserver (Apache or something similar), which runs as its own user. I would guess that there is something missing for this user that prevents the usage of gammu.

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig  so,what you are saying is it does not have access to execute this command, so how can i give root permission to this php file to execute the command? ,i have also tried sudo but it's not working

Comment: You should never ever give root access to a webserver. Ugh...horrible idea. Figure out what rights are required to actually be able to use gammu. And then consider if you really want your webserver to have access to each particular right. Then you could adjust the user the webserver is running as. (That's only a guess, however. I don't know gammu at all.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the user www-data to the group dialout to allow it to use any tty device:

```
sudo adduser www-data dialout
```